# Removing part of a file name before copy using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to rename files during the copy process and strip out part of the file name.  What I have been doing before users added to the file name was simple:

```
dir $PROCDIR\$PDFTYPE\holding_pattern\*.pdf -recurse | sort -property lastwritetime | select    -first 1 | move-item -destination $PROCDIR\$PDFTYPE\begin_processing
```

The file name format that I am working with is now xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx.pdf where the _ splits the information apart.  The x's are just an example because the file could be named LakeTahoe_February15_Airplane_0115201457_baseball.pdf.  When I perform the copy I need to keep the first three.... so from aaa_aaa_aaa_aaa_aaa.pdf to aaa_aaa_aaa.pdf.  Basically stripping out the last two.  Further if there is nothing beyond LakeTahoe_February15_Airplane_.pdf I want to get rid of the last "_" as well.

I am still very new with powershell but learning.  It is good stuff however frustrates me from time to time :).  Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex solution that might help you out:

```
dir $PROCDIR\$PDFTYPE\holding_pattern\*.pdf | sort -property lastwritetime | select    -first 1 | % { $_.Name -match '.*?_.*?_.*?(?=_)'; $Target = '$PROCDIR\$PDFTYPE\begin_processing\{0}.pdf' -f $matches[0]; Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Target -WhatIf; };
```

The results I got during my test seem to indicate that the move/rename operation was successful:

> What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\test\asdf_blah_asdf_qwer_trew_ytui - Copy.pdf Destination: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\$PROCDIR\$PDFTYPE\begin_processing\asdf_blah_a
>   sdf.pdf".

You can safely ignore the phony destination path in my example, since I don't have the `$ProcDir` and `$PDFType` variables defined.

Here's a version that's a bit more readable, on multiple lines.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test\*.pdf | 
Sort-Object -Property lastwritetime | Select-Object -First 1 | 
ForEach-Object -Process { $_.Name -match '.*?_.*?_.*?(?=_)'; $Target = 'c:\test\subtest\{0}.pdf' -f $matches[0]; Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $Target -WhatIf; };
```

Result:

> What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\test\asdf_blah_asdf_qwer_trew_ytui - Copy.pdf Destination: C:\test\subtest\asdf_blah_asdf.pdf".

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, inline and more succinct (this is the last stage of your pipleine; everything that precedes it stays the same):

```
| mi -Des $PROCDIR\$PDFTYPE\begin_processing\$(($_.Name -split '_')[0..2] -join '_').pdf
```

(`mi -Des` is the same as `Move-Item -Destination`; I used the short version to fit it into one line without scroll bars.)

What this does is splits the base filename into an array of the underscore-separated parts, selects the first three elements of the array (i.e., the first three parts of the filename), glues them back together with underscores, and tacks the `.pdf` extension back on.

Another approach is to use the **-replace** operator to match the part you want to get rid of and replace it with an empty string:

```
| mi -Des $PROCDIR\$PDFTYPE\begin_processing\$($_.Name -replace '(_[^_]+){2}(?=\.)', '')
```